# How to get the geolocation when an alphabet is typed in the field using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, geolocation

i have a address field, if i type an alphabet in that i need to get list of locations present in that alphabet and once the location is selected, i need longitude and latitude of that particular location also to be displayed. I have installed ng4-geoautocomplete but it is not working.

HTML:

```
<div>
   <ng4geo-autocomplete (componentCallback)="autoCompleteCallback1($event)"></ng4geo-autocomplete>
</div>
```

TS:

```
autoCompleteCallback1(selectedData:any) {

    }
```

App module:

```
import { Ng4GeoautocompleteModule } from 'ng4-geoautocomplete';

(NgModule({
  imports: [
    Ng4GeoautocompleteModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
```

Comment: Sorry, what is an alphabet ? What do you want to perform exactly ?

Comment: Thanks for response, I need like the first example in this https://tanoy009.github.io/ng4-geoautocomplete/

Comment: Why don't you use Google Maps API ?

Comment: i am new to this, i have no idea how i can do, Can you help me

Comment: Well, I don't need to, Google will do it : [here is a complete step by step tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

Comment: Thank you, i will try and update you